# unable save file in a shared folder on a remote ubuntu machine using notepad++

Tags: python, ubuntu

I use a shared folder to share files in linux with a windows machine. However, after i have edited a python file using notepad++ in windows, changed the owner of the file to the user of ubuntu, and run the file, i wanted to edit the file again, when i save the file, I get the following error.

> 'Please check whether if this file is opened in another program'

is it concerned with the linux daemon?? If both machines are windows, i can edit it as administrator, but i am new to linux, i do not know how to deal with it?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the process which is opening the python file
or you can reboot your windows
It may resolve the problem